# Form validation -> error message taken from label element .innerText

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate a form of which i want to show an error if the requirements are not met.
In this error i want to re-use the label text.

I didn't get very far, hence the error the console gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'innerText')
> at onSubmit (app.js:40:71)
> at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (contact.html?userName=&userEmail=&userComment=:43:69)

As to my understanding the text in the element/label(name, email, comments) should be stored to `let label`. But it gives me and error at `.innerText`.

```js
'use strict';
const onSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  for (let element of event.target)
    if (element.required) {
      let label = document.getElementById(`${element.id}-label`).innerText
      let error = ""
      switch (element.type) {
        case 'text':
          if (!isNullOrEmpty(element.value)) {
            if (!isMinLength(element.value, element.dataset.requiredMin)) {
              error = `Your ${label.toLocaleLowerCase()} must contain at least ${element.dataset.requiredMin} letters.`
            }
          } else {
            error = `You must enter a ${label.toLocaleLowerCase()}`
          }
          console.log('validera text');
          break;
        case 'email':
          console.log('validera email');
          break;
        case 'textarea':
          console.log('validera lösenord');
          break;
      }
      document.getElementById(`${element.id}-error`).innerText = error
    }
}

const isNullOrEmpty = value => {
  if (value.length === 0)
    return true

  return false
}

const isMinLength = (value, minLength = 2) => {
  if (value.length >= minLength)
    return true
  return false
}
```

```html
<section class="form container">
  <h1>Come in Contact with Us</h1>
  <form onsubmit="onSubmit(event)" class="contact" novalidate>
    <div class="name_email">
      <span>
        <label id="userName-label" for="userName-input">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName-input" placeholder="Your Name" required data-required-min="2">
        <div id="userName-error"></div>
      </span>
      <span>
        <label id="userEmail-label" for="userEmail-input">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail-input" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        <div id="userEmail-error"></div>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label id="userComment-label" for="userComment-input">Comments</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="userComment" id="userComment-input" placeholder="Comments" required data-required-min="10"></textarea>
      <div id="userComment-error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="submitbutton">
      <button type="submit" class="button bg-red">Post Comments</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: The ids of input and error elements don't match (compare "userName-input-error" to "userName-error"). Remove `-input` from the input ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the parameters of the `document.getElementById`. Your for loop goes through `input` elements, not `label`.

Just change the `id` value of your inputs in your Html, remove the `-input` at the end. Or,
Something like this should work.

```js
'use strict';
const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("el:",event.target)
    for (let element of event.target)
        if (element.required) {
            console.log("=>",element.id)
             // look at it
            let label = document.getElementById(`${element.id}`.replace('input','label').innerText
            let error = ""
            switch(element.type) {
                case 'text':
                    if (!isNullOrEmpty(element.value)) {
                        if (!isMinLength(element.value, element.dataset.requiredMin)) {
                            error = `Your ${label.toLocaleLowerCase()} must contain at least ${element.dataset.requiredMin} letters.`
                        }
                    } else {
                        error = `You must enter a ${label.toLocaleLowerCase()}`
                    }
                    console.log('validera text');
                    break;
                case 'email':
                    console.log('validera email');
                    break;
                case 'textarea':
                    console.log('validera lösenord');
                    break;
            }

            // look at it          
            document.getElementById(`${element.id}`.replace("input","error")).innerText = error
        }
}

const isNullOrEmpty = value =>{
    if (value.length === 0)
        return true
    
    return false
}

const isMinLength = (value, minLength = 2) =>{
    if (value.length >= minLength)
        return true

    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks it definitely helped. I get the result i want now. But i must ask, does it have to do with the `required` data type in the html?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question.

Comment: I was refering to the `if (element.required)` line.

Comment: teemu commented my post:

`The ids of input and error elements don't match (compare "userName-input-error" to "userName-error"). Remove -input from the input ids.`

Comment: Yes, only required fields will be checked.